# Self Join in try to show two year result

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hi I have one table which include 2016 and 2017 year cost.

my code is

```
    select 
    sum(a.cost),a.AGENCYNAME,b.AGENCYNAME,sum(b.cost) from table as a
    where a.projectyear = 2016 and b.projectyear = 2017
    join table as b on a.USERID = b.USERID
```

But I can not get the answer.

Comment: `WHERE` comes after `JOIN's`

Comment: Why do you want to use join and why not union of two result?

Comment: I want to show 2016 in one cloumn and 2017 in another cloumn :)

Comment: please remove one of the `dbms` tags among `mysql` and `oracle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I think what you are trying to do is quite simple and can be achieved using a CASE statement. I'm just not quite sure where the USERID comes into it.

```
CREATE TABLE #table(
   [userid] char(1),
   [agencyname] varchar(255),
   [projectyear] int,
   [cost] int
);
INSERT INTO #table VALUES
('A','Agency 1',2016,10),
('A','Agency 1',2016,20),
('A','Agency 1',2017,30),
('A','Agency 1',2017,40),
('A','Agency 2',2016,100),
('A','Agency 2',2016,200),
('A','Agency 2',2017,300),
('A','Agency 2',2017,400);

SELECT
       agencyname,
       SUM(CASE WHEN projectyear= 2016 THEN cost END) as 'cost 2016',
       SUM(CASE WHEN projectyear= 2017 THEN cost END) as 'cost 2017'
FROM #table
GROUP BY agencyname

DROP TABLE #table
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because I did not understand the question clearly, could not solve why we need self join here. Could you please try:

```
select a.AGENCYNAME, a.projectyear, sum(a.cost) as TotalCost
from table a
where a.projectyear in (2016,2017)
group by a.AGENCYNAME,a.projectyear
```

Comment: Hi Eray, I tried but only gave me two colum which the sum amount and the agency name.  No year exit.

Comment: That should give you 3 columns since there are 3 columns specified in the select clause: agencyname, projectyear. TotalCost ?

Comment: Got it missed a comma.  Thanks Eray

Answer (score 0):

You have join in wrong position  but you should add a proper group by

```
select 
sum(a.cost)
,a.AGENCYNAME
,b.AGENCYNAME
,sum(b.cost) from table as a
INNER join table as b on a.USERID = b.USERID
where a.projectyear = 2016 and b.projectyear = 2017
group by a.AGENCYNAME ,b.AGENCYNAME
```